# How is a particular form of the Dirac Spinor derived by a boost from the system of rest?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, dirac-equation, spinors

In Peskin-Schroeder Chapter **3.3: Free Particle Solutions of the Dirac Equation**
the form of the general Dirac Spinor $u(p)$ along 3-direction is derived from $u(p_0)$ in the system of rest by applying a boost. I understand how the following expression is derived from the already known transformation of spinors, which gives:

u(p) = \begin{bmatrix}
(\sqrt{E+p^3} \, \frac{1-\sigma^3}{2} + \sqrt{E-p^3} \, \frac{1+\sigma^3}{2}) \,\xi
\\ 
(\sqrt{E+p^3} \, \frac{1+\sigma^3}{2} + \sqrt{E-p^3} \, \frac{1-\sigma^3}{2}) \,\xi 
\end{bmatrix}

Here $\xi$ denotes any two-dimensional spinor, $\sigma^3$ the Pauli matrix for 3-direction
However, as a next step, they say: "the last line can be simplified to give"

u(p) = \begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{p \cdot \sigma} \, \xi
\\ 
\sqrt{p \cdot \overline{\sigma}} \, \xi
\end{bmatrix}

This is the point where I cannot follow...Even in my greatest imagination I cannot explain how $\sigma$ changes its place under the squere root. I'm sure to have a total blackout, but cannot find the problem I have...

By the way: One page before they introduced

$\sigma^\mu = (1, \vec \sigma)$

$\overline{\sigma}^\mu = (1, -\vec \sigma)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may wish to compare the squares of the coefficients at $\xi$ in the two lines.

Comment: Yes much easier, as I thought

Answer (score 1):

In the first equation for u(p), we substitute as follows

> $\sigma_3=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ and $1=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

When we substitute so we get the following

> $\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{E-p^3}&0\\0&\sqrt{E+p^3}\end{pmatrix}$

If we analyze the matrix $p \cdot \sigma$ for $p^\mu = (E,0,0,p^3)$, we find that it is a diagonal matrix as follows,

> $\begin{pmatrix}E-p^3&0\\0&E+p^3\end{pmatrix}$

Following which we can see that $\sqrt{p \cdot \sigma}$ can be shown to be one of the coefficients of $\xi$